# JMeter CSV run one by one

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I would like to call my API with *different* user id each time.

JMeter tree:

Thread Group
----While Controller
--------HttpRequest
--------CSV data set config

My CSV file:

```
111111111   
22222222   
33333333   
44444444  
55555555  
66666666  
77777777  
88888888  
99999999  
12121212
```

I want to run ONE user each SECOND,
so in 10 second all 10 users used exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) define 1000 as `Number of threads` and `Ramp-Up Period` as `100` seconds.  (Loop Count 1)

It will execute CSV rows as you required

> Ramp-up Period How long JMeter should take to get all the threads started. If there are 10 threads and a ramp-up time of 100 seconds, then each thread will begin 10 seconds after the previous thread started

Comment: Tested on 10 users - 
Number of threads 10
Ramp-Up Period 1
Loop count 1

all 10 executed at once.

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: according to logic you described it should execute one in each second.

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik 1/10 = 100/1000

Comment: @AlexanderGorelik you don't need the `While Controller`, just set 10 as Number of threads and Ramp-Up Period as 10 seconds to get user per second

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the thread numbers should be equal to the number of records in CSV so that 10 different threads login 10 different users in in 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit execution rate of JMeter's [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) to 1 request per second - add [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) as a child of the request you want to "slow down" and configure it like:

[image]

You can also consider [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which is more precise when it comes to shorter execution time frames and it has some more features like defining load patterns or connecting with the [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)

You can install Throughput Shaping Timer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)